# Method to check uniqueness of an XML attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, xml-attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<projects>
  <proj name="project1">
    <file_type Type="internal">"path1"</file_type>
    <file_type Type="external">"path2"</file_type>
  </proj>
  <proj name="project2">
    <file_type Type="internal">"path3"</file_type>
  </proj>
</projects>
```

This is my XML file. I need to add these `file_type` values to my ComboBox list. For that, I need to check the uniqueness of the attribute values. Here I want to add only intenal and external inside the ComboBox. Please tell me any method to check uniqueness of attribute value.

Comment: Are you using an XSD?

Answer (score 1):

You can get unique `Type` values with `Distinct()`:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml); // use Linq to Xml
var types = xdoc.Descendants("file_type")
                .Select(f => (string)f.Attribute("Type"))
                .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XML Schema and use ID for the attribute type.